# ¿Cómo parsear estos datos de un Json? 2ª PARTE

Tags: android, json

¿Me puede decir alguien cómo puedo mostrar las tarjetas amarillas y las sanciones de este Json?

```
 {
    "plantilla": [
          {
               "id":"UNA ID",
               "estadisticasCompeticiones":[
                       {
                         "goles":"100",
                         "amarillas":"30",
                         "dobles":"0",
                         "rojas":"1"
                       }
                ],
                "sanciones":[
                       {
                         "jornada":"18",
                         "sancion":"3 Partidos",
                       },
                       {
                         "jornada":"19",
                         "sancion":"1 Partidos",
                       },
                       {
                         "jornada":"28",
                         "sancion":"3 Partidos",
                       }
                 ]
          }
   ]
}
```

y este mi class:

```
            try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("plantilla");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Estadisticas plantilla = new Estadisticas();
                    plantilla.setNombre(object.getString("nombre"));



                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsono.getJSONArray("estadisticasCompeticiones");
                    Estadisticas plantilla1 = new Estadisticas();


                    plantilla1.setAmarillas(jsono.getString("amarillas"));
```

Comment: Mirate la libreria gson es muy practica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema lo estas teniendo en estos puntos

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsono.getJSONArray("estadisticasCompeticiones");
plantilla1.setAmarillas(jsono.getString("amarillas"));
```

ya que estas buscando el elemento que quieres dentro de `jsono` cuando deberías estar buscando ese elemento en el objeto siguiente `JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i)`; porque plantilla es una lista de objetos y lo que tu quieres son elementos de esos objetos, por lo que te recomiendo que hagas algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject objetoPlantilla = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

      JSONArray jsonArray = objetoPlantilla.getJSONArray("estadisticasCompeticiones");

      for (int y = 0; y < jsonArray .length(); y++) {
             JSONObject objetoEstadisticas = jsonArray.getJSONObject(y);

             //tratar las tarjetas amarillas
             String tarjetasAmarillas = objetoEstadisticas.getString("amarillas");

      }

      JSONArray jsonArraySanciones = objetoPlantilla.getJSONArray("sanciones");

      for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray .length(); x++) {
             JSONObject objetoSancion = jsonArraySanciones .getJSONObject(x);
             //tratar las sanciones
      }
}
```

El código lo he hecho en base a la estructura de tu `JSON`, espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Primero hay que validar JSON aquí: http://jsonlint.com/

> Error: Parse error on line 12: ...": `3 Partidos`,        }, {
>
> ```
>       "jornada":
> ```
>
> ----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', got '}'

Al español sería.

> Error al analizar la línea 12: "3 Partidos",}, {
>
> ```
>       "jornada":
> ```
>
> Se esperaba una cadena antes de '}'

Luego eliminar la coma `,`.

```
"plantilla": [
    {
        "id": "UNA ID",
        "estadisticasCompeticiones": [{
            "goles": "100",
            "amarillas": "30",
            "dobles": "0",
            "rojas": "1"
        }],
        "sanciones": [
            {
                "jornada": "18",
                "sancion": "3 Partidos"
            }, {
                "jornada": "19",
                "sancion": "1 Partidos"
            }, {
                "jornada": "28",
                "sancion": "3 Partidos"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hola @Maguz, estás en [es.so]. ¿Podrás traducir la respuesta? Además, conviene darle formato de código al JSON, seleccionandolo y haciendo click en el botón `{  }`.

Comment: @Mariano intenté editar la respuesta, habrá que esperar, me aparece que tiene que ser "revisada por pares", primera vez que lo intento.

Comment: gracias pro avisar